# How to enable user log in from the only one machine(by acquiring CPU Serial) to the ASP.NET-MVC web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

**Scenario:**

I have web deployed ASP.NET-MVC 5 application with individual user accounts: Identity 2.x. Every user has an e-mail and password to log in the web application via browser, this means that user can log via any device with internet browser.

I would like to enable user logging on condition that he uses exactly the same PC class machine every time he logs in.

I can politely ask user to run **any** desktop .NET(.exe) application if necessary. I can also ask user to use Chrome browser if the plugin is necessary to achieve this. Literally I can assume anything. The solution might be very uncomfortable, it's fine.

**My semi-solution:**

1. Obtain CPU serial number via desktop(let's call it Authorizer.exe) application which will send this unique ID to the ASP.NET-MVC Web Application while logging into it to authorize that user uses certain PC. Authorizer.exe would detect logging into Web Application by sniffing packets going through network.
   PLUS 
   Detect user's location, which restrains him from moving his computer.
2. Create desktop app which can be activated once only with unique serial provided from the web application. Login to the ASP.NET-MVC would be possible only if this desktop app is openned.(I have no idea how to do it).

**Why do I ask this question:**

If somebody steals user's e-mail and passwords I don't want to let the thief being able to login **but the most important to me is that** I don't want let user to log in from different devices.

Comment: Are you saying your desktops have GPS's in them and thus have location data available?  Or are you relying on the network information?

Comment: Also, I'm curious as to why this level of effort and frustration is worth the level of security?  Security is a balancing act between usability and security.  The most secure system possible is practically unusable.  So, you end up making measured compromises for usability, and tradeoffs trying to find the sweet spot of best security for least pain and frustration.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I rely on network informationn. The answer is, because I try to figure out interesting way achieve objective stated in scenario as little part of my thesis project and it does not really matter if it is little uncomfortable.

Comment: @Yoda i am not sure what is missing from your current sol, but i suggest that the Exe desktop app to get some kind of token from server, it's generated on server, the exe app send CPU-serial as param, and username maybe. the user then copy the token to login-form on web-app and server decides if this token is valid for this username, i can post detailed answer if that what you are asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of is to issue client certificates, and use certificate authentication in your application.

### Managing certificates

To manage certificates you need to implement a PKI, which requires:

- Get a Certification Authority, needed to issue the certificates (it can be a public CA or you can use self-signed certificates)
- Issue a Certificate for your web server, using the CA
- Configure your app to work via HTTPS, and require certificate authentication
- Issuing certificates for your users, and installing them in their browsers

### Ensuring the user cannot move the certificate to other machine

The weak link is the last. You must pay attentiton to how you install, and how you issue the certificate.

#### Installing the certificate on the user's browser

To install the certificate in the browser. You can:

- Create a certificate file, that be used to import the certificate in the browser
- Use a PKI infrastructure (certificate server) that allows a certificate to be requested by visiting a page with a browser, and requires to use the same browser to install the certificate in it, once it's issued (i.e. its request is accepted).

*NOTE: in both cases you have to accept the request and issue the certificate or reject it. Certificates are not issued automatically*

The first option has a problem: if you send the certificate to your user he'll be able to install it in any machine, any number of times. To solve this problem you'd need to get access to your user's machine, copy the file, install it, and delete it. The second option solves this problem.

The second option is safer. But a user with good knowledge can still recover the file issued by the server in this process, and install the certificate in a different place.

#### Making the private key non-exportable

Another very important point to take into account is that, when you issue a certificate there is generally an option that allows to make its private key exportable. If you set this option, the user can export the PK from the browser where it is installed, and install it somewhere else. Obviously you want to avoid this. So, disable this option.

With this option, the user can still export the certificate, but without its private key, so it can't be installed somewhere else.

### Setting up the PKI

I don't give additional details on how to setup the PKI, because it depends largely on the infrastructure (OS and version). If you want to know more about certificates and PKI the [wikipedia entry for "X.509"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) and [wikipedia entry for PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). Then you can look for additional information on setting a PKI in your particular infrastructure (OS).

#### Security of this system

You can rest assure this system is really safe: for example, in my country you can identify yourself by this means to make a lot of "official" things, like declaring and paying taxes.

#### Revoking certificates

And, if you're wondering what happens if you want to reject access to a user that already has a certificate. The answer is that you can revoke a certificate whenever you want, so that the server won't allow your user to authenticate with his certificate, because it's revoked.

#### User and machine safety

And another thing that can worry you is that other user takes the same machine and logs to your application. It's harder thanit looks like for this reasons:

- the certificate is only available when you log to he machine with the same user that installed it
- when installing the certificate you can make the OS to request a password when someones wants to use the certificate
- you can make your app to have double authorization:

  - first, the certificate authorization (this is, in fact, handled by IIS itself)
  - second, ask for a username and password (or use the certificate's user name, and ask for an additional password associated to the user)

## Edit: the dirty solutions, and the queen of all them, evercookie, that stores data in 12 different thinkable and unthinkable places

I've seen a lot of anwsers that propose using a "magic way" of identifying the user's machine, without him knowing and accepting it, and, or that can be broken by some user actions. Those solutions are unstable, and can even be not legal. Besides, none of the explained solutions is reliable or easy to implement, but the one that I'll so you at the end of my answer. But before this, allow me to explain why I prefer the certificates solution.

Installing an issued certificate is something which isn't hidden from the user, and that can't be broken unless the user deletes the certificate on purpose. The user can be informed that he needs the certificate to access the application, so you're neither cheating, nor making "magic" to identify his machine. It's a clean, supported, and documented solution. Besides a certificate cannot be caracked or hacked (in an strict sense, everything can be cracked or hacked, but this is way too hard to crack). Apart from this, the same certificate can be shared by all browsers, because it's not installed in the browser, but in the machine's certificate store. So, even if the user opens the application with a different browser, the certificate will still be there. And it's very easy to check if the problem to authenticate it's a missing certificate(or something related to it).

However, if you still prefer to implement a solution that can identify your user's machine without him approving it,or without explaining how it works, you can use "supercookies". If you google for thister you'll find in a lot of places that this exploits Flash storage. Or even Flash + HTML5 storage. Or it can use even many other places to store the required information. But you'll see that this techniques are frowned upon. And can be against the low and make you get into trouble. However, that said, if you still want to do this kind of "dirty" thing, you can use evercookie. It's implemented in JavaScript and you can see the information and donwload the code from this link:

- http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Disclaimer: if you use this evil thing and get into some kind of trouble, don't blame on me! I told you!

Comment: I've read it and it looks like a mature solution. I will give it more attention after tomorrow(I've got other BIG job to do), but it's probably the best till now. Thanks.

Comment: I've update my question, in case you decide to use an alternative way, that I don't like too much, but I think it's better than all other alternative solutions in the other answers

Comment: You may find Virtual Smartcard a 'more secure' option if you are in Windows only land. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593708.aspx I understand that client certs can generally be retrieved by the user if needed. An additional signing server on the network is likely your best proxy for location within a call center, but that wouldn't allow you to localize within a home environment.

Comment: @cacsar Please read the section on "Making the private key non-exportable". You'll understand that the user cannot move the certificate to a different machine, if you do it in the rigth way.

Comment: It's hard to find up to date information, but I believe in Windows land there will be a difference in terms of availability in debug mode or with test signing allowed. Virtual smartcard *should*  be better protected so http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/mimikatz for example won't work. Not a substantial concern, but resistance against users owning the machine is what the TPM is for.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is very difficult and requires a lot of work. I'd suggest you something much more simple.

First of all, you add a binary field 'FirstTime' to users db and init it with 'true' by default. 
When user make log in first time you drop him a cookie (I'd encrypt it for the better security) and change the field in user's record to 'false'. When user log in again you check this cookie and disallow him to log in if cookie not exists. Therefore, you let every user to log in one time from any place, and then he or she can log in only from the same browser and same machine.

See the following pseudo code:

```
Login (Email, Password)
{
    if (FirstTime)
    {
        DoLogin();
        SetCookie();
        FirstTime = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (GetCookie())
            DoLogin();
        else
            ConfirmError();
    }
}
```

An only weak point in this solution is the theoretical possibility that user may try to copy the cookie to another machine. It, however, requires from your users to be a quite good hackers, and from your description I suppose that they are not.

**UPDATE:**

I thought much about you problem and I'll try to suggest you an improved solution which is still easy in implementation, not requires a weeks of hard work, not costs a lot of money and not forces the customers to fulfill the complicated operations.

The idea is to combine a number of the client detection methods, while it's probably not so difficult to pass around each one them, but it's really problem to pass around all of them together.

So, you can do three things:

1. Set encrypted cookie. Even it's not a big problem to copy, it's one more operation the potential 'hacker' should not forget to do.
2. Duplicate it in the browser Local Storage. Again, it's possible to trick, but nobody said the cheater that he need do it.
3. Use the browser fingerprinting techniques. For more information on it read [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/is-browser-fingerprinting-a-viable-technique-for-identifying-anonymous-users). At least you can check the User Agent, HTTP Headers, Screen Size and Color Depth and the Browser Plugin Details. The probability that two browser's fingerprints will be close enough is low even inside the same organization.

All this information you can store per user in your DB and the combination of these factors will provide the reliable decision base. For example, if somebody has a cookie but the Local Storage record is missed, it's obvious that the cookie was copied. Disallow access and delete the cookie. Let's imagine the cheater came back to the original computer, found a Local Storage record, copied it as well and try to connect again... but it's already no cookie here! And don't forget about the browser fingerprint, which is more difficult to fabricate. If you limit the number of unsuccessful connection attempts during the certain period of time, it will be REALLY difficult to break your protection.

Comment: This weak point(copying the cookie)is the reason I didn't want to do it also if user cleans the browser it might be impossible to login. This is way I chose CPU serial number + localization(I know how to do this part) to unable user to log from different places and machines.

Comment: You don't need to be a hacker to copy cookies from one machine to other machine: you simply have to export and import them using the browser's tools.

Comment: @JotaBe Do you have any particular thoughts about problem's solution? Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: @JotaBe Are sure you putted this comment is in the right place? You answer seems not related to my answer...

Comment: Yep... but it's not a comment to your answer, but an answer to Yoda's comment. I should have addressed my comment to him to avoid the confussion. Sorry for that!

Comment: @Yoda I've added my own answer. I give you an introduction to the safest option I can think of, but the implementation details depend on your infrastructure. Please, read it.

Comment: 1&2 are fragile: an encrypted cookie can still be exported and imported. And both the cookie and the local storage will be removed if the user clears the cookies of his browser http://sharonminsuk.com/blog/2011/03/21/clearing-cache-has-no-effect-on-html5-localstorage-or-sessionstorage/. Some clean-up tools do this. 3. Any change in the characteristics used to compute the fingerprint will change it, so the machine will not be recognized. 1,2,3: If the user tries to open the app from a different browser in the same machine, it will fail. Many disadvantages, I think.

Comment: If you really want to implement this kind of solution, look at my updated answer. You have something much stronger, and already implemented.

Comment: @JotaBe You're right, it's certainly not the absolute solution. Certificates are much more secure... until a cheater has physical access to the client's computer (as far as I understood, in the Yoda's system it's possible). The executable which detects the unique machine by its hardware and software is excellent... until somebody changes a motherboard or installs a new version of OS. I mean that it's no absolute solutions in this world, but only something that may be good enough for the purpose. Finally, the developer should decide what he prefer. :)

Comment: @AlexanderDayan What do you mean by "until a cheater has physical access to the client's computer". What can the user do to "cheat" if he has access to his physical machine (what he, indeed, does)? Have I forgotten some detail? If you know how to steal certificates from one machine, then you have information that noone else has. Please, share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Checking any hardware info, such as CPU Id is imposibble with javascript, because it can't run out of browser's sandbox. Doing it with c# is possible though:

```
    public static string GetCpuId()
    {
        var mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select ProcessorId from Win32_processor");
        var mbsList = mbs.Get();
        var cpuId = "";
        foreach (var mo in mbsList)
        {
            cpuId = mo["ProcessorId"].ToString();
            break;
        }
        return cpuId;
    }
```

But there's no sence in it.
Imagine user tries to log in using email and password. Somebody's sniffing traffic and steals user's credentials. So he wants to sign in to your web app and realizes it's impossible because he also needs `CpuId`. Do you really think it's to hard too steal it together with password and after that do a fake sign in request to get cookie? No it's not.
Having desktop authorize application is even worse idea, cause any 10-year old cracker will hack auth tool in a few seconds.

IMHO, good way is to implement some kind of [`3D-secure`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-D_Secure), e.g. :

1. User enters his credentials on a sign in page
2. Application sends text message with some secret code to user's cell
   phone
3. User enter's code
4. Profit!

Also you need to use `HTTPS` for all secure-sensitive traffic.

If you don't want to let user use application from any other device - then you'll need to implement some `api` on server-side, that can be used by desktop application (client-side) with integrated hardware licensing

Comment: Thank you for elabioration on the subject. It might be my fault that I didn't stress enought that priority to me is preventing user from logging from another computer. Stealing password aspect is not so important and the SMS verification is an overkill in my case(Generaly great). To elaborate: I've written call center web app for my thesis and now I try to force user to work from one place to prevent him from doing it badly(for instance in inappropriate environment).

Comment: @Yoda, so your call-center app users will be distributed, or they'll work in a single office/some corporate network?

Comment: They will work from their homes(every employee in his/hers own home), on their own computers. Thanks for attention : ). The idea is: if they adapt their own environment as office and stick to it(don't do work in many places) the quality of their work will be better, they will  focus on work not on doing work aside something else.

Comment: To add: One must remember that usually call-center job is not treated seriously by employees because it's usually only temporal.(Before I went to college I worked in big call center, around 50 callers in one room + supervisors). So I try to develop a mechanism which would ensure(even partialy) quality of their work, and sticking to home office(one machine) is one of them. I would like to add that this is only concept(one feature to the whole system) for thesis so it might be super practical and realistic.

Comment: @Yoda: I don't understand how forcing them to a single machine is going to increase the quality of work. What if they install it on a laptop? That would bypass the whole staying-in-home-office thing.

Answer (score 1):

CPU Serial Number solution is not practical as others also mentioned that its not in approach of client side script.

However the idea regarding desktop application that came in to my mind is that once application is downloaded and activated through web, that application must keep the unique serial number with it. This desktop application will ping your web api/ web service after every (lets suppose) 30 minutes and will tell you that what is IP address of machine on which it is installed along with the unique serial number and save it in database. When a log in request comes to your web application, you will check that from which IP address this request is coming and is it the same IP address as provided by the call from desktop application or not.

Another idea but has a little loop hole:
If your users can allow ActiveX controls than following must work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cpu_id = "";
var get_cpuid = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}");
e = new Enumerator(get_cpuid.InstancesOf("Win32_Processor"));
for(; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
    var s = e.item();
    cpu_id = s.ProcessorID;
}
</script>
```

and than you can use it like:

```
<b>Client CPU-ID : </b><span id="show_cpu_id" />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("show_cpu_id").innerHTML = cpu_id;
</script>
```

but as it is on client side, so still user can manipulate the value and post some different value.

Comment: What about DHCP? It may change an underlying IP at any time.

Comment: Very bad idea. If the user is connected using ADSL, the IP changes frequently (at least whenever the router is reset) So, this will not work at all in most cases (is very strange that someone has a fixed IP).

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult problem. Few solutions comes to my mind:

- Use ActiveX on the client side to pass MAC address of client's device to the server and use it for authentication. This is quite reliable, since MAC is statically assigned to network interface card.
- Another option is to install some kind of certificate on the client machine and pass it during signing in. Similar way as the SSH key authentication does. This however requires that user is not able to move key between machines.

Comment: The first is not a bad option for this application, but, you must be aware that, for an application where secutiry is critical this is a bad option because today it's quite easy to make MAC spoofing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing) or to create a virtual machine with a virtual network card which has the MAC of your choice.

Comment: I tried securing an application by MAC address once. It stumbled when one of my customers showed me a network card that generated a new random MAC address every time it was rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

There are few possible ways to do this,

**Using Ever Cookies (https://github.com/samyk/evercookie)**

***Advantages :***

This is also a very reliable method of identification

***Disadvantages :***

This will not work if user re-install the OS / Or user cleans all the places the information is stored

**Executing an ActiveX control from the browser to fetch the CPU ID and it would be very accurate**

***Advantages***

This is a very reliable method of identification

***Disadvantages***

Each and every time user logs in it will prompt executing the ActiveX

Many browsers other than IE need configuration change / might not work

If user change the CPU of the PC this will not work

**Using flash cookies**

***Advantages***

This is also a very reliable method of identification

***Disadvantages***

User needs to has the flash player installed

This will not work if user re-install the OS

This will not work if user cleans the flash cookies

Answer (score 1):

You can act like a certificate issuer and issue a certificate for each machine and associate that with the user login. The user could even sign it.

This process is used by Apple to enable any Mac as a iOS/Mac developer. You have to create the request from your computer send it to the Member Center, a certificate will be created for your computer only using a private/public key scheme (cryptography).

That is similar to what you want. To guarantee that the user do not take the certificate or install it on another machine you could create a program that generates a random key and persist it into the computer. The certificate is created using that key. If the user tries to change the key the server will say that this key was not used to generate this specific certificate and, finally, the certificate can not be changed because it was generate by a private key which only the server knows.

Answer (score 0):

No browser is going to let you have the CPU Serial number without some kind of plugin. Also the way you get that information is going to vary between operating systems. As such you are going to have to write application code to run on the client machine. Given that you are losing most of the advantages of using web browsers to access your application.

What you can do is to write a simple desktop application that uses something like [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) to embed a rendering engine within it. Then you can write whatever security you like and embed the required tokens directly as http headers.

I did something similar a few years ago when I was writing a call centre application as it allowed me to invent a new URL scheme allowed me to control the operators phone.

Comment: I can't understand how awesomium can solve the problem at hand. Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: Basically your application does the web requests and gives awesomium  the response to render. You then handle events in awsomium to capture when it makes the next request and intercept that too.

Comment: Basically it is a cheap way of writing your own web browser.

Comment: Yes, I understand that awesomium lets you make your own browser, but, how do you solve the problem of running it in a single machine? Besides, making you own browser has the inconvenience that you must chek compatibility between your application and its rendering engine an JS VM... Too much work, I think. And, I can still see how it helps identifying the machine

Comment: Use WMI to get the CPU or Hard Disk serial numbers and add them as a http header to every http request.

Comment: This is what answers the original question, so it should be in the answer, not in a comment. You could edit it.