# Can one obtain CPU or motherboard serial number via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I would like to obtain CPU or motherboard serial number via JavaScript to pass it to my ASP.NET-MVC web application as part of login data.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Using out of the box JS you can't do that... specially in a browser that is secure... but if you have control over the environment (i.e. intranet) you could achieve this by deploying your own plugin

Answer (score 4):

A website can only request data from the client that the client has access to, and in this case, browsers do not have that info (for obvious security reasons).

You may be able to use a Java applet to do something like this (I believe the Dell website does something similar to get Service tags). Just know that some of your users may be hesitant about allowing Java, let alone sharing that info.

Comment: With Java the problem is(from my expierience) that even if you want to run Java applet, you can't, even if you are persistent and try to change security rules it's hell. This question is a mean to solve this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928367/how-to-enable-user-log-in-from-the-only-one-machineby-acquiring-cpu-serial-to